# Use foreign keys as where argument in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I'm pretty new to symfony/Doctrine and having some problems with querybuilder:

Given this ER:

[image: ER]

And following declaration:

```
namespace xxx\SeoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * xxx\SeoBundle\Entity\Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="session")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Session
{
    const repositoryName = "InternetSmSeoBundle:Session";

    /**
     * @var string $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;
......
    /**
     * @var Gsite
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gsite")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gsite_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $site;
......
}
```

I need to find sessions which filtering them by site.
I've tried following approach:

```
    $rep = $this->em->getRepository(Session::repositoryName);
    $qb = $rep->createQueryBuilder("s");

    $qb->setMaxResults(200);
    $qb->where("1=1");
    $qb->orderBy("time", "desc");

    //site
    if ($params->site != null){
        /** @var Gsite **/
        $site = $params->site;
        $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq("gsite_id",$site->getId()));
    }
```

Or even

```
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq("site",$site));
```

But it doesn't work. What is correct way to filter data in presence of Many To One foreign keys? Do I need to create declaration of gsite_id column in my Model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parameter, Doctrine will be able to infer the type (no need to use the foreign key `id`):

```php
$qb
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('site', ':site'))
    ->setParameter('site', $site);
;
```

Comment: line 0, col 58 near 'site = :site': Error: 'site' is not defined. Dql: SELECT s FROM xxx\SeoBundle\Entity\Session s WHERE site = :site ORDER BY time desc
EDIT: found my error, I had to prepend column with "s." i.e. $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq("s.site",":site"));